# Installing the DBPedia Extraction framework

Tags: java, dbpedia, information-extraction

I am trying to install the DBPedia extraction framework following the http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Documentation

I have downloaded the Maven binary version.

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 16:44:56+0800)
Maven home: /home/william/universe/Downloads/apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.5.0, vendor: Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.6-1.5.0.0/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.1.0-1.2-desktop", arch: "x86_64", family: "unix"
```

When at the extraction directory, I try to run this to install but got error.

```
dell:/home/william/Downloads/extraction_framework # mvn install
Sep 14, 2012 11:36:08 p.m. com.google.inject.internal.MessageProcessor visit
INFO: An exception was caught and reported. Message: java.util.NoSuchElementException
java.util.NoSuchElementException
   at java.util.AbstractList$2.next(libgcj.so.12)
   at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forMember(InjectionPoint.java:116)
   at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.<init>(InjectionPoint.java:73)
   at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint$InjectableMethod.toInjectionPoint(InjectionPoint.java:459)
   at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:725)
   at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:358)
   at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:377)
   at com.google.inject.internal.BindingBuilder.toInstance(BindingBuilder.java:84)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer$ContainerModule.configure(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:803)
   at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:229)
   at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
   at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:80)
   at org.sonatype.guice.bean.binders.MergedModule.configure(MergedModule.java:54)
   at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:229)
   at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
   at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:136)
   at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
   at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:94)
   at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:71)
   at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:61)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:470)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:196)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:160)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:375)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:191)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.12)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Sep 14, 2012 11:36:08 p.m. com.google.inject.internal.MessageProcessor visit
INFO: An exception was caught and reported. Message: java.util.NoSuchElementException
java.util.NoSuchElementException
   at java.util.AbstractList$2.next(libgcj.so.12)
   at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forMember(InjectionPoint.java:116)
   at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.<init>(InjectionPoint.java:73)
   at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint$InjectableMethod.toInjectionPoint(InjectionPoint.java:459)
   at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:725)
   at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:358)
   at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:377)
   at com.google.inject.internal.BindingBuilder.toInstance(BindingBuilder.java:84)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer$DefaultsModule.configure(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:836)
   at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:229)
   at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
   at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:80)
   at org.sonatype.guice.bean.binders.MergedModule.configure(MergedModule.java:54)
   at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:229)
   at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
   at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:136)
   at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
   at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:94)
   at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:71)
   at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:61)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:470)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:196)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:160)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:375)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:191)
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.12)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] null
```

Know what's wrong ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working, the JAVA_HOME should point to the JDK,

JAVA_HOME should be

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_02/
```

instead of

```
/usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.6-1.5.0.0/jre
```